# Setting up a defaultValue for Edittext

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm building a dice app with an editable dice maximum.
Well, it works. But if you delete everything in the edittext than the value of the Int i is like "null" and the app crashes.

To fix this, i tried many different things, like an exception or tons of "if"-code.

So my main problem isn't the defaultValue but the crash caused by a "non-input".

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you try to check if the editText.getText() is an empty string and if yes, then to set a new text to the editText like this for example edittext.settext("something default");

Comment: handle the exception and put the default value over there

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming *questions*. What is your *question*? If your question is "how do I do this?", since you already did it several times, please explain **in detail** what you tried and what specific problems you encountered with it. Android has `TextUtils.isEmpty()` to trivially check whether the value you get back is `null` or zero-length, so handling this validation would not seem to be terribly difficult.

Comment: @Shivam: Handling the exception would be kinda dirty. Better is to check for emptiness and for the right format (e.g. number).

Comment: @mad_manny I don't agree that handling the exceptions looks dirty :/ But the way you suggested is also good.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now.

Answer (score 4):

**If** EditText is empty, you can set an error on it. So user will have a visual indication of what is wrong.

```
EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
String strUserName = txtUserName.getText().toString();

 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
    txtUserName.setError("Your message");
    return;
 }
```

It will display something [like this.](http://blog.oestrich.org/images/android-edit-text-error.png)

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if this helped you. 
Nawako - Thanks for your answer, it helped me make my app better! Never heard of setError before!

Comment: Don't forget to cancel the error if the input is correct. To do it : `txtUserName.setError(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default value to your string variable if the edit text is empty

```
EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String variable;

if(editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
     variable="Empty";
 }else{
     variable=editText.getText().toString();
     /*Do the rest of the logic */
 }
```